# Problem in scheduling repeating local notification every hour

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification

Im trying to schedule local notification every hour. The problem is that im getting the notification in such irregular time. Sometime in 10 minutes, or in second, or 30 minutes. Sometime i get like 10 notifications in the same second suddenly. I have no idea what is the mistake im doing here. I apologize in advance, i just started learning swift.

This is my code.

```
@objc func LocalNotificationHour() {

    let user = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    user.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound]) { (granted, error) in}

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Local Notification"
    content.body = "Test."

    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (60*60), repeats: true)

    let uuid = UUID().uuidString
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuid, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    user.add(request) { (error) in print("Error")}
}
```

Comment: Hello Mustafa, Welcome to StackOverflow! No need to apologize. This is a good question, you attached the significant part of your code relating to this question and explained well what the problem is. Perfect! I will now have a look at your code and report back. From the first look, it seems pretty correct.

Comment: Did you try the code in simulator or real device? I am running your code in the simulator right now with timeInterval set to 60 (once per minute) and it's spot on, after 60 seconds the notification comes in. I'm pretty sure that on a real device there can be irregularities e.g. when the device is in low-power mode.

Comment: @unixb0y This is where it gets weird. I tested the code on my physical phone and it did work for 2 days and after that i started to face this problem. For the 60 seconds, im not having issue with this. It does work perfectly when i set it for 60 seconds. But im trying to set it for an hour only. or 2 hours which im having a difficulty with.

Comment: So if you try it again, you can reproduce the issue that it works hourly for 2 days and then stops working reliably?

Comment: @unixb0y yes. It did work for only 2 days then it stopped working. Do you see anything wrong in my code? specially the  let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (60*60), repeats: true)

Comment: No your code is absolutely fine. Either an iOS bug or a known limitation that I don’t know about yet (e.g. have to refresh the timer after 48h or so). Have you tried to recreate the timer for example once a day? Or upon App launch? Then, every time a user uses the App (hopefully at least once a day), it is created from scratch and the bug might be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your function is being run multiple times, and therefore scheduling more than one notification to repeat? That would account for receiving multiple notifications at once/at times when you're not expecting them.

If that is the case, try adding the line `user.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()` under `let user = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()`. This will remove any pending notifications your app may have scheduled before scheduling a new one.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are running your code once with one hour logic.

And then you are changing logic for two hour logic.

So basically both notification is triggering.

**Either delete the app or previously scheduled notifications or change the identifier.**